# RSA ENCRYPTION IN ANDROID AND DECRYPTION IN SERVER SIDE

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I have made a https api request from android to server. The API request contains one parameter that needs to be encrypted before it is send (i.e. it's a password). `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` is the encryption used in both end.

Encryption in android side does the following things:

```
/*Encrypt the password using public key.public key is obtained from generateRsaPublicKey(BigInteger modulus, BigInteger publicExponent) function)*/

public static String rsaEncrypt(String originalString, PublicKey key) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cipherByte = cipher.doFinal(original);
        return bytesToHex(cipherByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

//generate public key with given module and exponent value
public static PublicKey generateRsaPublicKey(BigInteger modulus, BigInteger publicExponent) {
    PublicKey key = null;
    try {
        key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent));
      return key;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.toString());
        // return null;
    }
    return key;
}

// Helper methods

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
       // Log.d("byte array representaion","value in integrer"+v);
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];           
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

below is the source for decrypting the password on the server

```
// *** setup private key

RSAPrivateKeySpec privateRPKS
= new RSAPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(gModulusPlainS, 16), new BigInteger(privateExponentPlainS, 16));
KeyFactory keyFactoryKF = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey gPrivateKeyRPK = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactoryKF.generatePrivate(privateRPKS);

// *** setup cipher
Cipher cipherC = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipherC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, gPrivateKeyRPK);

// *** decrypt hex-encoded cipherTxS
byte[] baCipherText = hexToBin(cipherTxS.getBytes());
byte[] baPlainText2 = cipherC.doFinal(baCipherText);
String decryptedTextS = new String(baPlainText2);
```

But I got the following error log

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data size too large
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.RSASSL.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.RSASSL.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Not PKCS#1 block type 2 or Zero padding
```

But it is working on websight part. Why it isn't working in android?

Thank you for your kindness to looking my code.

Comment: 1) HTTPS already encrypts everything. So what's the point in encrypting again. 2) PKCS#1v1.5 padding is insecure. Use OAEP instead.

Comment: point 1:https encrypts overall url string.But inorder to improve the security we need ssl encryption so that's y using encrypting password.thats common methods used in every authentication.    for point 2:I already know the factor.But the api is given from client.Actually oaep is the newer version of PKCS#1v1.5 padding.Anyway thank you for your help.can u help solve this problem?

Comment: Both your code as well as your comment to CodesInChaos show big misunderstandings about cryptography. That said, I think it is very brave of you to teach Codes cryptography.

Comment: In mobile side i had check my encryption with followeing online rsa calculator,that seems both are correct(http://nmichaels.org/rsa.py).So i think there is probelm in byte to hex conversion in mobile side and reverse thing in server side.I had respect codesInChaos ,but i just comment why i should follow that method behalf of its security.Here the problem with rsa  encryption in android side and decryption in server side.not the cons or prons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Klyubin, Android Security Engineer. I have got answer from [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html)

> Developers who use JCA for key generation, signing or random number generation should update their applications to explicitly initialize the PRNG with entropy from /dev/urandom or /dev/random.Also, developers should evaluate whether to regenerate cryptographic keys or other random values previously generated using JCA APIs such as SecureRandom, KeyGenerator, KeyPairGenerator, KeyAgreement, and Signature.
>
> *Code comment:* Install a Linux PRNG-based SecureRandom implementation as the default, if not yet installed.This is missing from jellybean onwards.

[Sample code implementation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the ciphertext as string, if `cipherTxS.getBytes()` is indeed a string to byte array conversion. Ciphertext should be either kept in binary or possibly encoded using base 64 encoding.

Comment: Note that this answer may only solve the immediate problems with your code, in my opinion CodesInChaos is correct. Just a hint: take a look at replay attacks and authentication using challenge/response.

Comment: actually problem where the byte to hex conversion in mobile side and hex to byte conversion in server side.The above decryption and cryptography part is implemented by another person.I had already check with UTF-8,base64 and org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex encodeing methods inorder to standardise the conversion in bothends.I couldn't obtain positive response.

Comment: So the problem *is* with the encoding. Either accept this answer or indicate why it is incorrect. If you have another question please indicate.

Comment: what should be the solution.?I had using different encoding standard but they wont lead to me for a positive result.I had also tested both encryption and decryption in mobile side,they work perfectly in mobile side.